# How can I connect the servlet address to my tic tac toe(used html, javascript)

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I am currently doing a game called tic tac toe.. The thing I want to do is when I open the app/game and anyone who also open the app/game can join my game.. I tried to do some research how to connect it to servlet address(because it's 2 players) and I dont know how.. Any suggestion/help will be appreciate thank you!

Note: You cant press "ready to play" button if there's no other player

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tic-tac-toe">
        <!-- 1st row -->
        <div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="0"></div>
        <div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="1"></div>
        <div class="grid" data-row="0" data-column="2"></div>
        <!-- 2nd row -->
        <div class="grid" data-row="1" data-column="0"></div>
        <div class="grid" data-row="1" data-column="1"></div>
        <div class="grid" data-row="1" data-column="2"></div>
        <!-- 3rd row -->
        <div class="grid" data-row="2" data-column="0"></div>
        <div class="grid" data-row="2" data-column="1"></div>
        <div class="grid" data-row="2" data-column="2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="turn fixedToTop">Player 1's turn</div>

            <!-- Start overlay -->
    <div class="start-overlay">
        <div class="start-message">
            <span class="theMessage">
            Welcome to tic-tac-toe
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="lets-play">Ready to play!</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- overlay message - win/lose/draw -->
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="message">
            <h1>Game Over</h1>
            <span class="theMessage">
            Well done Player 1, You've won the game!
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="play-again">Play another round</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="tictactoe.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet Address**

Servlet address:

```
http://192.168.160.112:8080/TicTacToeServer/tictactoeserver/createGame?
Parameter (key=yourId)
Responses (X,O,[GAME ALREADY STARTED])

http://192.168.160.112:8080/TicTacToeServer/tictactoeserver/move?
Parameter (key=yourId&tile=playerTile&y=yPos&x=xPos)
Responses (::::::::: + Update,[TAKEN])

http://192.168.160.112:8080/TicTacToeServer/tictactoeserver/reset?
Parameter (key=yourId)
Responses ([EXIT],[NO GAME TO RESET])

http://192.168.160.112:8080/TicTacToeServer/tictactoeserver/check?
Parameter (key=yourId)
Responses (true,false)

http://192.168.160.112:8080/TicTacToeServer/tictactoeserver/board?
Parameter (key=yourId)
Responses (:::::::::)
```

**Java file?**

```
public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) 
{  
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");  
    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getHeader("Proxy-Client-IP");  
    }  
    else if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getHeader("WL-Proxy-Client-IP");  
    }  
    else if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");  
    }  
    else if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");  
    }  
    else  if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {  
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();  
    }  
    return ip;  
}
```

Question: Where should I put this java code/how should I use this??(this is what I saw through my research)

Comment: try coding something and when you have a problem then ask.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I edited my post, thats what I saw through my research..